# mvc function inside view returning route values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to return route values in my view using a function:

VIEW:

```
@functions {    
    public Dictionary<string, object> GetFilters()
    {
        var filters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var f_phrase = this.Request["f_phrase"] ?? string.Empty;
        var f_site = this.Request["f_site"] ?? string.Empty;
        var f_device = this.Request["f_device"] ?? string.Empty;
        var f_startdate = this.Request["f_startdate"] ?? string.Empty;
        var f_enddate = this.Request["f_enddate"] ?? string.Empty;
        var f_package = this.Request["f_package"] ?? string.Empty;

        filters.Add("f_phrase", f_phrase);
        filters.Add("f_site", f_site);
        filters.Add("f_device", f_device);
        filters.Add("f_startdate", f_startdate);
        filters.Add("f_enddate", f_enddate);
        filters.Add("f_package", f_package);

        return filters;
    }
}
```

Then on my link I want to be able to do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export file", "Export", "Log", new { @GetFilters() }, new { @class="iconDocumentText"})
```

but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) on the `routeValues` parameter:

> An object that contains the parameters for a route. The parameters are
>   retrieved through reflection by examining the properties of the
>   object. The object is typically created by using object initializer
>   syntax.

So you need to construct an object and return that instead of returning a dictionary (not sure, but maybe you can achieve this with `dynamic`/`ExpandoObject` or just create a custom type with properties named according to your route values).

Example:

```
public class FilterRouteValues
{
    public string f_phrase { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public FilterRouteValues GetFilters()
{
    // Read from request, fill an instance of FilterRouteValues
}
```

Markup:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export file", "Export", "Log", GetFilters(), ...)
```